# Registered user cant login in joomla2.5 front end

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

While user logs-in in joomla2.5 site , it sets sessions for the user and in user.php it prints current user id,name and all. But after redirection everything lost and it shows as guest visiting page.

while user logs-in 4 sessions are created one for user and remaining 3 as guest.

Answer (score 0):

We had this case before, and the login page had no www in the URL, but it was redirect to a page that had www. Could that be the reason?

If that isn't the reason, then worst case scenario you can just download Joomla (the version of the downloaded version of Joomla should match yours), and then extract it onto your website, and then remove the installation folder.

Comment: May redirection cause the issue, tried in localhost user gets logged in without problem